# how to split dart class in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I did the following test, but it doesn't work:

```
//main.dart
class Test
{
  static const   a = 10;
  final b = 20;
  final c = a+1;

}

//part.dart
part of 'main.dart';
class Test
{
  final d = a +1;   //<---undefined name 'a'
}
```

I would like to split the class in [flutter tutorial](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/) into multiple files. For example: _buildSuggestions in a separate file, _buildRow in a separate file, etc.

**update:**

my solution:

before:

```
//main.dart
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
{
    final _var1;
    final _var2;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      ...
      body: _buildList(),
    );

    Widget _buildList() { ... }
    Widget _buildRow() { ... }
}
```

after:

```
//main.dart
import 'buildlist.dart';
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
{
    final var1;
    final var2;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      ...
      body: buildList(this),
    );

}

//buildlist.dart
import 'main.dart';

  Widget buildList(RandomWordsState obj) {
     ... obj.var1 ...
  }
```

Comment: You can just import other files if accesss to private members isn't an issue. Which part isn't answered by my answer or which part of what you want to accomplish does cause you troubles?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dart doesn't support partial classes. `part` and `part of` are to split a **library** into multiple files, not a class.

Private (identifiers starting with `_`) in Dart is per library which is usually a `*.dart` file.

**main.dart**

```
part 'part.dart';

class Test {
  /// When someone tries to create an instance of this class
  /// Create an instance of _Test instead
  factory Test() = _Test;

  /// private constructor that can only be accessed within the same library
  Test._(); 

  static const   a = 10;
  final b = 20;
  final c = a+1;
}
```

**part.dart**

```
part of 'main.dart';
class _Test extends Test {
  /// private constructor can only be called from within the same library
  /// Call the private constructor of the super class
  _Test() : super._();

  /// static members of other classes need to be prefixed with
  /// the class name, even when it is the super class
  final d = Test.a +1;   //<---undefined name 'a'
}
```

A similar pattern is used in many code-generation scenarios in Dart like in

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_redux
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable

and many others.

Comment: I got the following error in fultter: The return type '_Test' of the redirected constructor isn't assignable to 'Test'. The class 'Object' doesn't have a constructor named '_'.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `extends Test` - fixed

Comment: Thanks, it works now! So if I want to split class Test into multiple file, just create multiple classes which extend from Test, right?

Comment: It depends on why you want to split it. Above pattern is (as mentioned) used for code generation, where one file is hand-written and the other is generated automatically. For purely hand-written classes this shouldn't be necessary. If classes become too big you probably need specialize your classes mire.

Comment: Is it possible to use `part` not in library as well? I had tried but w/o success.

Comment: @BambinoUA sorry, but I don't understand what "use `part` not in library" means. Can you please elaborate what you try to accomplish?

Comment: I mean in regular code of regular flutter project (template is "app" not "package", "module" or "plugin"). I tried to use it with `import`s but it looks like it is impossible.

Comment: There is no difference in this regard between app, package, module, plugin, but I would need more information to guess what could be the issue.

Comment: It looks like `part of` can be used only in files which does not contain `import` statements.

`The part-of directive must be the only directive in a part.
Try removing the other directives, or moving them to the library for which this is a part.`

And then I don't understand when this practice used...

Comment: Actually I had an idea to separate `AppState` classes depending of target platform but use only `single` class in the code

```
final appState = AppState();
```
So when I type `AppState` only single file would be suggested instead of 3 ones if I would use conditional export.

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question. Usually using `part`/´part of` of is a bad idea, except for code generation (like built_value, and others) where there are no alternatives. Everything in `lib/src` is private by convention. If you don't want others to use something, do not export it from public files i(files in `lib/`)

Answer (score 25):

I am faced with same problem. My variant based on extensions:

**page.dart**

```
part 'section.dart';

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
    build(BuildContext context) {
        // ...
        _buildSection(context);
        // ...
    }
}
```

**section.dart**

```
part of 'page.dart';

extension Section on _PageState {
    _buildSection(BuildContext context) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this looks like a cool way to use partial files (like C# visual Studio).

Do you know if there is some information pro or against this practice?

Comment: @adrianvintu iOS developers use in this way on swift. After compilation this is the same as one big class.

Comment: As a Swift dev, this is exactly what I was looking for! The only new thing is having to declare the `part` inside the main `class` file and its associated `part of` in your `extension`. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution! You will have to remove all other directives from section.dart, e.g. import directives, in case there are, as it was the case with my code.

Comment: Hey I also use the same method to split large class in flutter, everything is as intended only problem is that if setstate is called from extended class, it works fine but a warning is given  - The member 'setState' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'.

Answer (score 6):

I just extend it with extension keyword like Swift.

```
// class_a.dart
class ClassA {}

// class_a+feature_a.dart
import 'class_a.dart';    

extension ClassA_FeatureA on ClassA {
  String separatedFeatureA() {
    // do your job here
  }
}
```

Please ignore the coding conventions, it's just a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I learn from tutorial way, select a class name and use Refactor menu, choose `Move XXXClass to file`, it will auto generate new file and insert `import` to your code.

tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first?hl=zh-cn#4

IDE: vscode

Open Refactor shortcut (Mac): CMD + .