# using "mixin" to factor out code to different files

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to factor out some code(inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594307/how-to-split-dart-class-in-flutter))

part "game.dart":

```
part 'taps.dart';

class MyGame extends FlameGame with HasTappables {}
```

Trying to factor out to this file "taps.dart":

```
part of 'game.dart';

mixin Taps on MyGame {

  @override
  void onTapDown(int pointerId, TapDownInfo info) {
    super.onTapDown(pointerId, info);
}
```

Problem is that "onTapDown" is not called?

Update:

This will not work:

```
class MainClass with OneMixin {
  void test(){
    helloOne();
  }
}

mixin OneMixin on MainClass {
  void helloOne() {
    test();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't use the `Taps` mixin and uses some other `HasTappables` mixin instead.  Assuming that your `Taps` mixin was meant to be named `HasTappables`, that example and the example from your update don't make sense because they're circular. `class MainClass with OneMixin` means that `MainClass` derives from an automatically generated class that copies `OneMixin`'s implementation (which in turn depends on `MainClass`).  I highly recommend reading [lrn's explanation for mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45903671/).

Comment: Also, none of this involves or is related to `part`/`part of`.  That's a completely independent concept from mixins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```dart
abstract class FlameGame {
  int? a;
}

class MyGame extends FlameGame with Taps {
  int? b;
}

mixin Taps on FlameGame {
  void method() {
    print(a); // Possible
    print(b); // Not possible
    print((this as MyGame).b); // possible but unsave
  }
}
```